# Как реализуется архитектура КОП на уровне исходного кода?

Tags: ооп, разработка-игр

Каким образом реализуется концепция Компонентно-ориентированного программирования (КОП) на уровне исходного кода? Как пример, есть простейший объект:

```
object:
    posX
    posY
    width
    height
    image
```

Выводится изображение `image` в позиции `posX`, `posY` экрана с размерами `width` и `height`. Допустим, нам из этого объекта, используя концепцию КОП надо сделать "кликабельный" элемент, то есть, он должен отлавливать событие/сообщение нажатия мыши, проверять, попадает ли курсор внутрь объекта и, по необходимости, вызывать событие `onClick`.

Что представляет собой `компонент`: вложенный объект или дополнительный класс/интерфейс, расширяющий функциональность базового класса? Как решается описанная выше задача с использованием концепции КОП?